# Angular - how to switch between expressions without losing user input

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular so please ELI5 if possible :)

I have a multiple-choice questionnaire with the setup for each question as below:

**Question**

- Choice A
- Choice B
- Choice C

My controllers look like this:

```
scope.questionnaire = [
  {
     questionEN: "Thing?",
     choice1EN: "Yes",
     choice2EN: "No",
     choice3EN: "Maybe",
     questionPR: "Treasure?",
     choice1PR: "Yarrr",
     choice2PR: "Arrrrr",
     choice3PR: "Parrrrley"
  }
]
```

My current questionnaire looks like this:

```
    <div ng-bind="questionnaire.questionEN"></div>
    <input type="radio" name="{{questionnaire.questionEN}}" ng-model="questionnaire.choice" ng-value="questionnaire.choice1EN">{{questionnaire.choice1EN}}</input> <br />
    <input type="radio" name="{{questionnaire.questionEN}}" ng-model="questionnaire.choice" ng-value="questionnaire.choice2EN">{{questionnaire.choice2EN}}</input> <br />
    <input type="radio" name="{{questionnaire.questionEN}}" ng-model="questionnaire.choice" ng-value="questionnaire.choice3EN">{{questionnaire.choice3EN}}</input>
```

What I want to do is that at the start of the questionnaire, there are two buttons that will let the user select between languages.

`[English]` `[Pirate]`

So I have two questions, actually:

1. How do I do the language swapping without losing the user input (for example: they have answered questions 1-5 in `[English]`, and while reading #6, scroll back up and hit the button to swap to `[Pirate]`. Their selected answers for 1-5 should remain, but all questions+choices have been "translated").
2. Is there a better way of arranging my controllers?

Comment: The value should not change after a user switches between two languages.

Comment: @KemalFadillah Yes, but I'm not quite sure how to do the switch. I'm new to Angular so I'm not familiar what 'directive' would be the best option here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this really varies on your particular set of needs. Start with developing a logical model of the problem you are trying to solve.

Things to ask yourself:

1. Are the questions dynamic (loaded from a database) or static?
2. How do I need to store the answer? Can I store a choice ID, key, etc. or do I have to use the human readable value?
3. Does the model that captures the answers have to be different than the model that presents the question?
4. Do you need to store the language they selected along with the answers?

As you think about it more, other questions will follow.

Anyways, to give you something close to an answer here is a suggestion. If the questions are dynamic, you'll want to create a better structure for defining questions and the choices that are related to them. I'd also give them a key or ID so they can be referred to as concrete concepts. Not only does this help tie the model to database entries, making storing and retrieving easy, it makes it easier for you to handle the language issue.

[Here's an example of such a design.](http://plnkr.co/edit/B38GYGslWxYrm5cN1kfI?p=preview) You may wish to track the answers separately if your design requires, in my case I just kept it simple and kept the questions and answers in one model.

The question model is an array of objects that look like this:

```
  {
    key: 'q1', // unique key for question
    text: { // a dictionary of language codes and the text of the question in that language
      'en': 'What is the answer the question 1?',
      'pr': 'Ahoy 1?'
    },
    choices: [{
      key: 'q1a1', // a unique key for the choice
      text: { // a dictionary of language codes and the text of the choice in that language
        'en': 'Answer 1', 
        'pr': 'Arr 1'
      }
    }, {
      key: 'q1a2',
      text: {
        'en': 'Answer 2',
        'pr': 'Arr 2'
      }
    }],
    value: null // the field that stores the user's selected choice
  }
```

There is a helper function to get the language-specific text of the selected choice:

```
  $scope.getAnswer = function(question) {
      var answer = $filter('filter')(question.choices, {key: question.value});

      if (answer.length == 1) return answer[0].text[$scope.selectedLanguage];

      return '(no answer)';
  };
```

The meat of your HTML template that displays the questions looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in model">
  <label>{{question.text[selectedLanguage]}}</label>
  <div>
    <label ng-repeat="choice in question.choices">
      <input type="radio" name="{{question.key}}" ng-value="choice.key" ng-model="question.value" />{{choice.text[selectedLanguage]}}
    </label>
  </div>

</div>
```

### Alternative

For the heck of it, [here's yet another example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vsu3bh2mMNjwy4yjt2vF?p=preview) of how you might do it. This method is useful if you do not have dynamic question/choice data, but with some effort could still be used for dynamic data. It involves keeping localized UI strings in separate tables, assigning questions and choices unique keys, and then using a translation service to retrieve the correct string. In this example, I use the [`angular-translate`](http://angular-translate.github.io/) module. I load it with tables of localization strings during `.config` of my module, specify a default language, and just use the `translate` filter when displaying questions and choices. This lets me greatly simplify my question model and get rid of some extra work in the views and controller.

My questions simply become:

```
{
  key: 'q1',
  choices: [
    'q1a1',
    'q1a2'
  ],
  value: null
}
```

I add a watch on the language dropdown to change the current language:

```
  $scope.$watch('selectedLanguage', function(value) {
      if (value === null) return;
      $translate.use(value);
  });
```

And clean up the template:

```
  <label>{{question.key | translate }}</label>
  <div>
    <label ng-repeat="choice in question.choices">
      <input type="radio" name="{{question.key}}" ng-value="choice" ng-model="question.value" />{{ choice | translate }}
    </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a function using ng-click then set your $scope to a new questionnaire.

So you would have something like this:

```
   var english = {
     question: "Thing?",
     answers: {
       choice1: {text: "Yes", val: 1},
       choice2: {text: "No", val: 2},
       choice3: {text: "Maybe", val: 3}
     }
    }

   var pirate= {
     question: "Treasure?",
     answers: {
       choice1: {text: "Yarrr", val: 1},
       choice2: {text: "Arrrrr", val: 2},
       choice3: {text: "Parrrrley", val: 3}
     }
    }
   // default
   $scope.questionnaire = english;
   $scope.choice;
   // change language
    $scope.changeLanguage = function (lang) {
      switch (lang) {
        case 0: 
         $scope.questionnaire = english;
         break;
       case 1: 
         $scope.questionnaire = pirate;
         break;
     }
   }
```

Then for your buttons

```
<button ng-click="changeLanguage(0)">English</button>
<button ng-click="changeLanguage(1)">Pirate</button>
```

and finally, I would suggest using ng-repeat in your questionnaire

```
<div ng-bind="questionnaire.question"></div>
<label ng-repeat="answer in questionnaire.answers" ><input type="radio" name="{{questionnaire.question}}" ng-model="choice" ng-value="answer.val" />{{answer.text}} <br /></label>
```

Comment: Wow, that looks pretty sound. Can't test it at the moment but I can't see anything that would go wrong. Thank you! How would your `english` and `pirate` vars work with multiple questions with differing choices for each question?

Comment: Hello, it wasn't working so I updated my answer. You essentially need to set the value to be the same so that your answer stays when the language chnages, because in this method you are swapping out the entire questionnaire. Then you can set your answer to a choice variable in scope. If you have multiple questions, you can expand the $scope.choice to be an array of many choices.